# Defining polygons based on thickness maps using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, geometry, polygon-creation

I want to find and create polygons that demarcates three different inflection points in a thickness raster: where the thickness start to increase, where the thickness is at its max and where it starts to flatten again (i.e. increase from the opposite direction). Please see the different interpolation lines in the attached figure. Warm colors define thin areas.
I want to do this quantitatively, instead of qualitatively drawing polygons by hand as in the example.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2

[image: Isopach thickness map with profile graph along highlighted interpolation line]

Comment: What Tools are you using, it helps to know for the correct answer .. Please edit your question and the tags to reflect the software package ..

Comment: Good point, sorry that! I'm using ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're wanting. Polygons are going to be areas. Lines can be breaks. You say three inflection points. So are there three polygons (thin, transition, thick), or two (from thin up to max, then max down to thin) which is what I see in your example? You're either looking at generating contours from the surface and polygons out of those, or reclassifying your raster to three classes and then using raster to polygon on that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Curvature GP tool in Spatial Analyst that may be helpful. It can tell you how convex or concave a surface is. For example it can be used to determine ridges and valleys. You would still need to convert the output raster to vector - likely it would be lines that you convert to initially.